# Django Generic CreateView - how to populate fields but not display them

Tags: django, django-views

I want to create hidden fields that are pre or post populated using the generic CreateView but as far as I can see I only have two choices that do not require specifying a form.

This will display the fields prepopulated:

```
class FootCreate(CreateView):
    model = Footprint
    fields = ["source","size","notes", "parent", "created_by"]
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')

    def get_initial(self):
        parent = Object.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['obj_id'])
        return { 'parent': parent, 'created_by': self.request.user }
```

Or remove the fields I don't want to display from the fields list:

```
    fields = ["source","size","notes"]
```

but now the fields are not populated on the form so it doesn't validate.

I know I can handle this by subclassing the form or using javascript to hide the fields on the form but I wondered if there is an option to have the equivalent of:

```
    fields = ["source","size","notes", "parent", "created_by"]
    hidden_fields = ["parent", "created_by"]
```

within the view?

**ANSWER**
No - But a custom model form takes only a few lines.  Give full list of fields in the view.:

```
class FootprintForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Footprint
        widgets = {'created_by': forms.HiddenInput, "object": forms.HiddenInput}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I now there is no way to do what you want in CBV and  I think there is no reason to do it in the View. The form logic should be encapsulated in the Form and you can do it easy with ModelForm and few lines of code

Comment: Good to know.  Added solution using form above.  Thanks.